# Making simple tabs in android

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-tabhost

### I am new to Android. I am making a tab Activity that has 3 tabs in it.

.
**I came across reading some interesting articles that tab can be made in four ways::**

- Regular TabHost Using
- simple Fragments Using
- Action Bar Sherlock
- Greendroid

---

**I have a set of questions**

- Which is a better choice & why ?
- Which gives more flexibility, efficiency & performance ?
- Which would be the preferd choice in case of requirement changes
  happen in future ?

---

**My research indicate** ::

- ActionBarsherlock is better !
- Is there something better than this ?

If so what is it ?

Comment: If you want to support all API levels then go for view pager..

Comment: worth reading http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html